# Delete last x-number of lines in txt file if it contains characters, in bash

Tags: bash, sed, text, delete

I have a list of .txt files in a folder and I would like to delete the last 50 lines (whole lines) IF they contain letter characters. So far I have the following:

```
for i in *.txt
do max_line=$(cat ${i%.txt}.txt | wc -l)
   let min_line=max_line-50
   #
   sed -e "${min_line},${max_line}d" %{i%.txt}.txt
done
#
```

Comment: 50 lines EXcluding lines with no letters, or INcluding those? In other words - 50 lines in case one, or less than 50 in case two? – RudiC 15 mins ago

Comment: Do ALL 50 lines have to contain text? You need to be much more specific about your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tac file | awk '/[[:alpha:]]/ && ++CNT <= 50 {next} 1' | tac
```

or

```
tac file | awk '/[[:alpha:]]/ && NR <= 50 {next} 1' | tac
```

First will check if last lines contain letters, and, if yes, count 50 of them and kick out ==> exactly 50 lines kicked.
Second will check 50 lines, and, if contains letters, kick out ==> less than or equal 50 lines kicked.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern to search in the last 50 lines is "PATTERN":

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    n=$(($(cat $f|wc -l)-50+1));
    [[ $n -lt 1 ]] && n=1;
    sed -i "$n,$ {/PATTERN/ d}" $f;
  done' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

You said it is a file, the use a file editor.

```
for f in *.txt; do
  printf '%s\n' '-49,$g/pattern/d' w | ed -s "$f"
done
```

Assuming files are not empty, that should work otherwise add a test inside the loop if file is empty and ignore/skip it. This solution will actually edit the files in place so test with some sample files and please backup first because it will delete lines with `pattern` in it from the last 50 line.